# Error with deploying the newsletter portlet in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am facing the problem with deploying the newsletter portlet in my theme, the error occurred is **java.net.UnknownHostException: mime** .
Will be thankful for any of your help :)

The issue of mime is solved. I had to do the smtp and pop3 settings for gmail.

But now I am facing one more issue in which it is not able to fetch the database of liferay and so can't create its tables.

**Here is the liferay-persistence.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- liferay database connection -->
    <bean id="liferayDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.InfrastructureUtil" factory-method="getDataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="liferayDataSource" />
        <property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rcs.newsletter.core.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" /> 
    
    <tx:annotation-driven /> 
</beans>
```

Finally solved the problem, had made changes in the database integration in `portal-ext.properties` file for changing the default database that Liferay uses and thats it. It solved the issue.

As I used the MySQL database, I added the following line of code in `portal-ext.propertie`s file:

> jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferay?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
>
> jdbc.default.username=root
>
> jdbc.default.password=root

Comment: which newsletter portlet would that be?

Comment: Its rcs newsletter, i found the link from the liferay community forums containting the admin and frontend portlets. The above issued of mime is solved but their is one more problem, where this newsletter doesn't find the database and cant create the tables automatically.